# Extent report - PIE chart not showing in DARK theme

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Pie chart is visible in LIGHT mode in EXTENT test report. But not showing in DARK themed report.
What will be the issue then?

> if i comment this line 'sparkReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);' pie chart is displaying fine.
> But, if i uncomment, report is generated in Dark mode. But PIE chart is not displaying. Corresponding area becomes empty. No problem with other areas of report including other configuration like 'report name','Document title' etc.,

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void initializeTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        launchApplication();
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
        loginPage.loginAsTL();

        extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        sparkReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter("Generated HTML Report.html");
        //sparkReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK); //Not showing pie chart - if uncommented.
        sparkReporter.config().setReportName("Application Test Report"); // works fine
        sparkReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Application Test Report"); // works fine
        extentReports.attachReporter(sparkReporter);
    }
```